# Add new product categories programmatically in Woocommerce

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am working on a Wordpress site and I am using Woocommerce, I have a lot of product category's and I would like to add them in the code and not in the Wordpress CMS itself.

Does anyone know how I can get into the code where I can add the category's. I have looked everywhere and I just cant find it even in the database. And also I would like to change my menu in the code because that would also be a lot less work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Woocommerce Product category terms are a WordPress custom taxonomy `product_cat`…

> **In the database** the data is located under the tables `wp_terms`, `wp_term_taxonomy`,  `wp_termmeta` and `wp_term_relationships` too.

**1) To add a new product category term** programmatically you will use the dedicated WordPress function [`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) like:

```
// Adding the new product category as a child of an existing term (Optional) 
$parent_term = term_exists( 'fruits', 'product_cat' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given

$term_data = wp_insert_term(
    'Apple', // the term 
    'product_cat', // the Woocommerce product category taxonomy
    array( // (optional)
        'description'=> 'This is a red apple.', // (optional)
        'slug' => 'apple', // optional
        'parent'=> $parent_term['term_id']  // (Optional) The parent numeric term id
    )
);
```

This will return the an array containing the `term Id` and the **Term taxonomy Id** like :

```
array('term_id'=>12,'term_taxonomy_id'=>34)
```

---

**2) Menu Order:** To set or even change the menu order of your product categories, you will use [`add_term_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta) Wordpress function.

You will need the term Id of your product category and the unique ordering numeric value (Here **`2`** for example):

```
add_term_meta( $term_data['term_id'], 'order', 2 );
```

---

**3) Thumbnail:** You will also use [`add_term_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta) to set a thumbnail ID to a product category using something like *(where the last argument is the numeric thumbnail ID reference)*:

```
add_term_meta( $term_data['term_id'], 'thumbnail_id', 444 );
```

---

**4) Set a product category in a product:**

Now **to set this new product category "Apple" to an existing product ID** you will use something like *(with the corresponding generated `$term_id` from new created "Apple" product category)*:

```
wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, array($term_data['term_id']), 'product_cat', true );
```

For reference: Function [`wp_set_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms)